# Dijit vertical layout

Tags: dojo

I need to create a list of buttons inside a ContentPane (one under the other) as a "single column vertical grid". I did not found such a layout widget in dijit ref. guide.

What can I use? How can I get a new line when adding (addChild) elements to a content pane?

There's dojox grid container but looks overkill to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know that this is the least elegant way to do it but it is one-of-a-kind: you could create a custom div-domNode containing your buttons just like this:

```
    var btn1=new dijit.form.Button({...});
    var btn2=new dijit.form.Button({...});

    // custom div-domNode
    var buttons = dojo.create('div');

    // filling it with the domNodes of your buttons separated by a <br> node
    dojo.create(btn1.domNode,null,listOfButtons);
    dojo.create('br',null,listOfButtons);
    dojo.create(btn2.domNode,null,listOfButtons);
```

and display it in you ContentPane

```
    myContentPane.set('content', buttons);
```

A ul or a table would work as well. 
Finally let me say that im very ashamed of myself for not knowing any better answer.
Hope its what you asked for.

Comment: honstely, i hate my response. So i want to add i guess a grid container may be even better than this. Have you thought about using a dijit.menu? ([link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/Menu.html)).

Comment: btw.: an other crappy method would be to set a fixed width to your ContentPane and Buttons, so that each button is implicitly placed in a new line as a line would be to tigth for 2 ;)